# MySQL Find minimum price row for multiple same product

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have product table with many same product but different condition and different supplier/vendor and i want to get a product with cheapest price and it's other data.

**Here some Entry**

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|    ID    |    Product Name    | new_price | old_price  |    price   |  provider_id |  condition  |
+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|    1     |   samsung tv 32    |   1200    |    null    |    null    |       2      |     new     |
|    2     |   samsung tv 32    |    null   |    null    |     800    |      123     | refurbished |
|    23    |   samsung tv 32    |    null   |     300    |    null    |       6      |     used    |
|    48    |   samsung tv 32    |   1500    |    null    |    null    |       8      |     new     |
|    2     |    smart watch     |    null   |    null    |     200    |      123     | refurbished |
|    23    |    smart watch     |    null   |     100    |    null    |       6      |     used    |
+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Desire Result**

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|    ID    |    Product Name    |   price   |  provider_id |  condition  |
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|    23    |   samsung tv 32    |    300    |       6      |     used    |
|    23    |    smart watch     |    100    |       6      |     used    |
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

here is my query what i tired.

```
SELECT
    MIN(
        IF(
            new_price > 0,
            new_price,
            IF(
                old_price > 0,
                old_price,
                IF(
                    price > 0,
                    price,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS price,
    `name`,
    `id`,
    `provider_id`
FROM
    `products`
GROUP BY
    `name`
```

Comment: can you give a query to make the `table`..

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired result set you can use a self join with `coalesce` to get first non null value.

```
select p.ID,
p.name,
coalesce(p.`new_price`, p.`old_price`, p.`price`) as price,
p.provider_id,
p.condition
from products p
left join products p1 on p.name  = p1.name 
and coalesce(p.`new_price`, p.`old_price`, p.`price`) > coalesce(p1.`new_price`, p1.`old_price`, p1.`price`)  
where p1.ID is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7eb20/5)

Another approach to get the same results using join

```
select p.ID,
p.name,
coalesce(p.`new_price`, p.`old_price`, p.`price`) as price,
p.provider_id,
p.condition
from products p
join (
  select name, min(coalesce(`new_price`, `old_price`,`price`)) as price
  from products
  group by name
) p1 on p.name  = p1.name 
and coalesce(p.`new_price`, p.`old_price`, p.`price`) = p1.price
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7eb20/9)

Comment: can you please explain how `p1.id` is null?

Comment: You can see the left join part `some value > some value`, In  your case when price 300 of first table p is not greater than any price of second table p1  then you will get a null row for p1, In short those rows with null values for p1 are your required rows with cheapest price, For more clarification see fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7eb20/6 and this one also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7eb20/7

Comment: wow thank you so much for great explanation. also i made an mistake while writing question in my actual database there is zero instead null in my database. so what should i do in this case should i  modify something like this `coalesce(if(p.new_price=0,null, p.new_price), if(p.old_price=0,null, p.old_price), if(p.price=0,null, p.price)) as price` or is there any other approach?

Comment: @HumairaNaz you can use [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function like `greatest(p.new_price, p.old_price, p.price)`

Comment: One more question if you can go with this. how can i make this query with laravel eloquent model? i am confuse how should i write in join query within eloquent.

Comment: @HumairaNaz Can you a ask a new question for this ? I will try to answer it